# How to resize ext3 image files

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3

I have created an 200MB ext3 using the following commands.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./system.img bs=1000000 count=200
mkfs.ext2 ./system.img
tune2fs -j ./system.img
```

How can I resize it to 50MB and 300MB? The problem is I have only some binaries in my system. They are : `badblocks,e2fsck, mke2fs, mke2fs.bin, parted, resize2fs, tune2fs`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, run a filesystem check, `e2fsck -f ./system.img`. Without this, it may proceed to enlarge the raw file, but fail to make any meaningful changes to the filesystem.

To reduce the size of the file system:

```
resize2fs ./system.img 50M
```

To enlarge:

```
resize2fs ./system.img 300M
```

resize2fs automatically adjusts the file size for you.

Comment: I just edited this answer to suggest running `e2fsck` first. I had problems where `resize2fs` would merely increase the size of the image file, without making any meaningful changes to the filesystem.

Comment: My version of resize2fs (1.42.13, Ubuntu 16.04) actually insisted I run 'e2fsck -f' first.